# read CSV coming from rest-api in Angular-8

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a rest-api which is returning csv file, how can i get it in the angular service.

```
 getCSV() {
    let headers_object = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       'Authorization': "Bearer "+ "7woNSuuEYqLfQAuqwHhCJn8aq2SM"
    });

        const httpOptions = {
          headers: headers_object,
          Accept: 'text/csv'
        };


   this._http.get(
                  'https://00.00.xx.00:9001/abcd/export', httpOptions
                 ).subscribe(resp => {
                  console.log(resp)
                  }
                );
  }
```

Data is coming in network tab, but angular goes into the ERROR status saying `http failure during parsing for` because somehow it is expecting the json return.

Please help[image]

Headers in POSTMAN as attached in image.